# GNU tar with --exclude-cache fails to exclude directories containing a CACHEDIR.TAG file

Tags: tar

According to the GNU tar manual page, directories containing a `CACHEDIR.TAG` file can be excluded by specifying a command-line option, such as `--exclude-cache` .

This doesn't seem to happen.

```
$ mkdir -p t/a/b/c
$ touch t/a/b/foo t/a/b/CACHEDIR.TAG
$ tar --exclude-caches-all -cvf /dev/null t
t/
t/a/
t/a/b/
t/a/b/c/
t/a/b/CACHEDIR.TAG
t/a/b/foo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A look at the GNU tar source code (and then at the [Texinfo documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html)) reveals that the file needs to contain [a special signature](http://www.brynosaurus.com/cachedir/spec.html).  Adding this signature to the file fixes the problem.

```
$ mkdir -p t/a/b/c
$ touch t/a/b/foo
$ echo Signature: 8a477f597d28d172789f06886806bc55 >t/a/b/CACHEDIR.TAG
$ tar --exclude-caches-all -cvf /dev/null t
t/
t/a/
tar: t/a/b/: contains a cache directory tag CACHEDIR.TAG; directory not dumped
```